# Get Custom Field Values by Another Custom Field in WordPress

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, custom-field, advanced-custom-fields

I have a custom post type named **houses**.
Inside this post type I have several custom fields, like:

(name - field type - meta key)

- Title (wordpress field)
- City (taxonomy - city)
- Condominium (custom post type - condominium)
- Beach (custom post type - beach)
- Country (taxonomy - country)
- Description (custom field - description)
- Text (custom field - text)
- Bedrooms (custom field - bedrooms)
- Bathrooms (custom field - bathrooms)
- Type (taxonomy - type)
- Status (taxonomy - status)
- Area (custom field - area)
- Full Area (custom field - full_area)
- Place (taxonomy - place)

and more.

I have a plugin on my website with 4 selects:

- City
- Beach
- Type
- Status

What I need to do is, update these selects when I select an option.

For example, if I select Barcelona for **City** and Sale for **Status**, I need to retrieve all **Types** and **Beaches** with these options in common.

I don't need to get the posts now, just update the select options, like a filter.

Here an example:

[image: Filter with selects]

PS: I'm using Advanced Custom Fields.

Comment: For making answering easier, could you include the `meta_key`s for each field? And are they all meta, not taxonomies? Is it too late to make these taxonomies? Also, you mentioned a plugin, do you have direct control over how these selects are populated?

Comment: Thanks, @JacobPeattie! I have updated the information with the meta keys and the type of each field. Most of them are taxonomies and custom post types. And about the plugin, I have total control over it and how I populate them. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After struggling with this, I found a workaround that worked.

Since every custom field has a connection with my custom post type, I was able to use wp_get_object_terms to get the terms for each custom taxonomy.

Using the query to retrieve all posts:

```
$args = array(
   'post_type' => 'houses'
);
$houses = new WP_Query($args);
$posts = $houses->posts;

// get an array with all ID fields
$my_post_ids = wp_list_pluck($posts, 'ID');
```

After that I can get the terms for these IDs above:

```
$city_terms = wp_get_object_terms($my_post_ids, 'cities');
$status_terms = wp_get_object_terms($my_post_ids, 'status');
$type_terms = wp_get_object_terms($my_post_ids, 'type');
```

And to have the behavior I needed when an option is selected in order to refresh the selects information, I had just to update the query for that. For example, if I selected some city:

```
$args = array( 
  'post_type' => 'houses',
  'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
      array(
        'key' => 'city',
        'value' => 107,
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
      )
    )
);
```

To do the filter, just need to add a new relation inside the meta_query array.

```
$args = array( 
  'post_type' => 'houses',
  'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
      array(
        'key' => 'city',
        'value' => 107,
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
      ),
      array(
        'key' => 'status',
        'value' => 80,
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
      )
    )
);
```

All of this combined with Ajax to make the data update for each select.